# django+celery+ansibleApi return None

Tags: python, django, ansible, celery, ansible-2.x

python call ansibleApi with celery return None,I have searched a few days.It works well with call deploy function without celery ,but with celery my code call ansibleApi return None.

reproduce steps.

1.tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task
from .deploy_tomcat2 import django_process


@shared_task
def deploy(jira_num):
    #return 'hello world {0}'.format(jira_num)
    #rdb.set_trace()
    return django_process(jira_num)
```

2.deploy_tomcat2.py

```
from .AnsibleApi import CallApi

def django_process(jira_num):
    server = '10.10.10.30'
    name = 'abc'
    port = 11011
    code = 'efs'
    jdk = '1.12.13'
    jvm = 'xxxx'

    if str.isdigit(jira_num):
        # import pdb
        # pdb.set_trace()
        call = CallApi(server,name,port,code,jdk,jvm)
        return call.run_task()
```

3.AnsibleApi.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
from .Logger import Logger
from django.conf import settings
from collections import namedtuple
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory import Inventory
from ansible.playbook.play import Play
from ansible.executor.task_queue_manager import TaskQueueManager
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase

Log = Logger('/tmp/auto_deploy_tomcat.log',logging.INFO)


class ResultCallback(CallbackBase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ResultCallback ,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.host_ok = {}
        self.host_unreachable = {}
        self.host_failed = {}

    def v2_runner_on_unreachable(self, result):
        self.host_unreachable[result._host.get_name()] = result

    def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result, *args, **kwargs):
        self.host_ok[result._host.get_name()] = result

    def v2_runner_on_failed(self, result, *args, **kwargs):
        self.host_failed[result._host.get_name()] = result


class CallApi(object):
    user = settings.SSH_USER
    ssh_private_key_file = settings.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE
    results_callback = ResultCallback()
    Options = namedtuple('Options',
                         ['connection', 'module_path', 'private_key_file', 'forks', 'become', 'become_method',
                          'become_user', 'check']) 

    def __init__(self,ip,name,port,code,jdk,jvm):
        self.ip = ip
        self.name = name
        self.port = port
        self.code = code
        self.jdk = jdk
        self.jvm = jvm
        self.results_callback = ResultCallback()
        self.results_raw = {}

    def _gen_user_task(self):
        tasks = []
        deploy_script = 'autodeploy/tomcat_deploy.sh'
        dst_script = '/tmp/tomcat_deploy.sh'
        cargs = dict(src=deploy_script, dest=dst_script, owner=self.user, group=self.user, mode='0755')
        args = "%s %s %d %s %s '%s'" % (dst_script, self.name, self.port, self.code, self.jdk, self.jvm)
        tasks.append(dict(action=dict(module='copy', args=cargs),register='shell_out'))
        tasks.append(dict(action=dict(module='debug', args=dict(msg='{{shell_out}}'))))
        # tasks.append(dict(action=dict(module='command', args=args)))
        # tasks.append(dict(action=dict(module='command', args=args), register='result'))
        # tasks.append(dict(action=dict(module='debug', args=dict(msg='{{result.stdout}}'))))
        self.tasks = tasks

    def _set_option(self):
        self._gen_user_task()

        self.variable_manager = VariableManager()
        self.loader = DataLoader()
        self.options = self.Options(connection='smart', module_path=None, private_key_file=self.ssh_private_key_file, forks=None,
                                    become=True, become_method='sudo', become_user='root', check=False)
        self.inventory = Inventory(loader=self.loader, variable_manager=self.variable_manager, host_list=[self.ip])
        self.variable_manager.set_inventory(self.inventory)

        play_source = dict(
        name = "auto deploy tomcat",
            hosts = self.ip,
            remote_user = self.user,
            gather_facts='no',
            tasks = self.tasks
        )
        self.play = Play().load(play_source, variable_manager=self.variable_manager, loader=self.loader)

    def run_task(self):
        self.results_raw = {'success':{}, 'failed':{}, 'unreachable':{}}
        tqm = None
        from celery.contrib import rdb;rdb.set_trace()
        #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        self._set_option()
        try:
            tqm = TaskQueueManager(
                inventory=self.inventory,
                variable_manager=self.variable_manager,
                loader=self.loader,
                options=self.options,
                passwords=None,
                stdout_callback=self.results_callback,
            )
            result = tqm.run(self.play)
        finally:
            if tqm is not None:
                tqm.cleanup()

        for host, result in self.results_callback.host_ok.items():
            self.results_raw['success'][host] = result._result

        for host, result in self.results_callback.host_failed.items():
            self.results_raw['failed'][host] = result._result

        for host, result in self.results_callback.host_unreachable.items():
            self.results_raw['unreachable'][host]= result._result
        Log.info("result is :%s" % self.results_raw)
        return self.results_raw
```

4.celery worker

```
celery -A jira worker -Q queue.ops.deploy -n "deploy.%h" -l info
```

5.produce msg:

```
deploy.apply_async(args=['150'], queue='queue.ops.deploy', routing_key='ops.deploy')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems OK.
The only question is `None` is really the `deploy` task return?
It will be better that if you can post your celery worker log.

Comment: `[2017-02-27 16:46:08,554: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: autodeploy.tasks.deploy[a963d1f3-cc1b-48da-9701-28297f7b68a5]`
`[2017-02-27 16:46:08,786: INFO/PoolWorker-2] result is :{'success': {}, 'failed': {}, 'unreachable': {}}`
`[2017-02-27 16:46:08,808: INFO/PoolWorker-2] Task autodeploy.tasks.deploy[a963d1f3-cc1b-48da-9701-28297f7b68a5] succeeded in 0.18285173299955204s: {'success': {}, 'failed': {}, 'unreachable': {}}`

Answer (score 0):

there are two method to solve this problem ,disable assert：
1.where celery starts set export PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1 OR start celery with this parameter -O OPTIMIZATION
2.disable python packet multiprocessing process.py line 102:

```
assert not _current_process._config.get('daemon'), \
               'daemonic processes are not allowed to have children'
```